# Cant get my solve function to run

Tags: equation-solving

[image: Code picture]

Solve function on mathematica not working. I'm doing a large solve function with several hyperbolic trig functions inside, and it just runs forever. Ive let it sit for a day and it still didnt run. Ive also tried adding Reals into the solve function and ive tried using NSolve as well.
I was trying to get it to run without values for the given variables but if it need be, put the values in.

Comment: You can edit your other question by clicking the "edit" button below the text of your question.

Comment: ive been trying to post the code for 30 minutes now. i press control k then i paste my code and it still says it isnt formatted properly.

Comment: Solve[{1 == a \[Mu]m (  Sinh[(x10 - xm)/a] + Sinh[(xm - x20)/a]), 
  0 == a Cosh[-x10/a] + y10, 0 == a Cosh[(x2 - x20)/a] + y20, 
  l1 == a Sinh[(xm - x10)/a], 
  l2 == a (Sinh[(x2 - x20)/a] - Sinh[(xm - x20)/a]), 
  a Cosh[(xm - x10)/a] + y10 == a Cosh[(x20 - xm)/a] + y20}, {a, xm, 
  x10, y10, x20, y20}]

Comment: Do you have an idea of approximately what values your variables should take?

Comment: If you can fix the value of `a` such as `a -> 1 ` the equation system solves. Maybe other variables too. That can be a start point.

Comment: a should be a single digit number around 1, xm will be negative. all values will be around 1. they will all be single digit i think.

Comment: when i say single digit i mean between 0 and 10. can u tell me what u mean by a \to 1

Comment: is there a way to tell the solver function that a should be around 1?

Comment: I wrote it as first the command `eqns = {1 == a mm (Sinh[(x10 - xm)/a] + Sinh[(xm - x20)/a]), 
  0 == a Cosh[-x10/a] + y10, 0 == a Cosh[(x2 - x20)/a] + y20, 
  l1 == a Sinh[(xm - x10)/a], 
  l2 == a (Sinh[(x2 - x20)/a] - Sinh[(xm - x20)/a]), 
  a Cosh[(xm - x10)/a] + y10 == a Cosh[(x20 - xm)/a] + y20}`

Comment: Then `Solve[eqns/. {mm ->400 , l1 -> 1, l2 -> 1, x2 -> 1, a -> 1},{x10, x20, xm, y10, y20}]`

Comment: assuming mm is supposed to be [Mu]m, its giving me an empty set.

Comment: @MikeY please dont go to sleep on me yet i need help. can you show me a picture of your mathematica sheet having it work?

Comment: See other version of your question, I gave an answer there to get you moving (hopefully)

Comment: @MikeY it wouldnt let me tag you on the other post, but i need the "a" value most importantly from the solve function. Can you help me find a way to find that?